# Infinite-dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness

Let $A$ be a compact self-adjoint operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space H. Suppose $(\lambda_n)$ is a sequence of different eigenvalues of $A$ and $(x_n)$ is a sequence of corresponding eigenvectors with $\| x_n \| = 1$.

> Is the set $S = \{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_nx_n\ : \alpha_n \in \mathbb{C}, \  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} | \alpha_n |^2 < \infty \}$ closed?

I know that self-adjoint operators are closed. If $(y_n)$ is a sequence in $S$ converging in $H$, say to $y$. Then, due to compactness of $A$, the sequence $(Ay_n)$ converges to $Ay$. Since $A$ is closed $y \in S$.
But I am not sure if this is a correct proof.

Comment: I don't understand this step: "Since $A$ is closed $y \in S$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why $S $ is closed is that the sequence $\{x_n\} $ is orthonormal (this follows from $A $ selfadjoint).

In your reasoning, if $y_n\to y $ then $Ay_n\to y $ because $A $ is bounded;  compactness has nothing to do with it. And the "$A $ is closed" bit is nonsense; there are selfadjoint compact operators with dense range (typical example ism $A $ that maps the canonical basis by $e_n\mapsto e_n/n $.

Comment: I do not understand your comment about closedness. Every self-adjoint operator is densely defined, closed and symmetric. And closed means, that its graph is closed (in our case in $H \timesH$)

Comment: How do I use the fact, that $(x_n)$ is orthonormal to prove that $S$ is closed?

Comment: Yes, but "closed operator" does not mean "closed range", so the fact is irrelevant to your reasoning. The point is that in general the set $S$ is strictly larger than the range of $A$.